# Fully remap a key to work as right alt

Tags: keyboard-layout, xmodmap

I'm using Linux Mint 18.3. My keyboard has a nonsensical key setup where I have an extra `\` key right before the right alt, and I keep using it by mistake. Since I don't need the `\` key there at all, I decided to remap it to an extra alt with this command:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 94 = ISO_Level3_Shift"
```

This seems to work, but not quite. The "proper" right alt button allows me to write capital letters with either `Shift+Alt` or `Alt+Shift`, as long as both buttons are pressed down. E.g. to write `Ó`, I could either press `Shift+Alt+o` or `Alt+Shift+o`. However, the new remapped key works *only* with `Alt+Shift`. Needless to say, if my muscle memory was OK with this, I wouldn't be writing this question.

So, is it possible to fully remap an arbitrary key as right alt and make it work for `Shift+Alt` shortcuts?